# Which ReadFile parameter in this code is incorrect? (Error code 87)

Tags: c++, port, readfile

(**Edit:** I didn't exclude any code except the headers and the main() function's brackets. Nothing is written between lines of code listed here.)

.

I used the ReadFile function to read this COM3 port (which returned no INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE or ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND):

```
LPCTSTR portName = "COM3" ;

HANDLE hSerial;
hSerial = CreateFile(portName,
                     GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                     0,    // exclusive access
                     NULL, // default security attributes
                     OPEN_EXISTING,
                     FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                     NULL);
```

And the ReadFile function in question uses following parameters:

```
DWORD n = 512 ;
char szBuff[n] = {0};
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;

if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
{
    cout << "ReadFile error. Error code: " << GetLastError() << endl ;
    cin.get() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

What changes should I introduce to cause the read to succeed?

(I searched through the function's documentation and other StackOverflow questions, tested lots of things, but couldn't find an answer.)

Comment: You assign a value to `hSerial`, then 1) You never checked for NULL and 2) your code disappears and reappears again in a `ReadFile` function, losing any track of what happened to `hSerial`.

Comment: @Paul I checked `hSerial` immediately after creation - not NULL. And the `ReadFile` occurs immediately after creating `hSerial`. Still 87.

Comment: `LPCTSTR portName = "COM3" ;`  You may want to change this, as `LPCTSTR` is a pointer to a wide string if a Unicode build is being done.  `LPCTSTR portName = _T("COM3");`

Comment: I suppose it is compiled with mingw and no UNICODE, for example: `DWORD n = 512 ; char szBuff[n] = {0};` is a variable length array use, CreateFileW would not accept `char` array.

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski Yes, but "officially", initializing an LPCTSTR  to a non-wide string literal is not really 100% correct.  If the app is going to use `LPCTSTR`, then it should be using the Microsoft-ism if using `_T()` macro or `TEXT` macro.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree, OP should use `LPCTSTR portName = _T("COM3") ;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation you can read:

> lpOverlapped [in, out, optional]
>   A pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure is required if the hFile parameter was opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, otherwise it can be NULL.

so since you specified `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in CreateFile you should provide `OVERLAPPED` in ReadFile.

In [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you can read on parameters for `Communications Resources`:

> ... and the handle **can** be opened for overlapped I/O.

so you can skip `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in CreateFile

Answer (score 1):

Marcin Jędrzejewski's answer is correct about the mismatch between the overlapped IO Flag and the `ReadFile` function, but I will leave this up just to be helpful.
You are missing a lot of initialisation which may be helpful to you when operating a COM port.

This code is used to open, configure, and read from a COM port on windows using C++.

### FOR REFERENCE

```
READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
COM_READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
COM_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
READ_TIMEOUT = 50;
WRITE_TIMEOUT = 100;

port = "\\.\COM6"
portFormat = "9600,N,8,1" /* for information on this, google the MODE command for windows. */

HANDLE hComPort;
DCB dcbComConfig;
```

### OPENING COM PORT

```
DWORD dwStoredFlags = EV_BREAK | EV_ERR | EV_RXCHAR;
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

FillMemory(&dcbComConfig, sizeof(dcbComConfig), 0);
dcbComConfig.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbComConfig);

/* assign a COM format to the COM Port. */
if(!BuildCommDCB(portFormat, &dcbComConfig))
{
    printf("Failed to build comm format data %s\n", portFormat);
}

/* Open the COM port with overlapped IO. */
hComPort = CreateFile(port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, 
                OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

if (hComPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Error opening port %s\n", port);
}

/* Set the COM Ports internal Read and Write buffer sizes. */
if(!SetupComm(hComPort, COM_READ_BUFFER_SIZE, COM_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE))
{
    printf("Could not set COM buffers\n");
}

/* assign the previously created COM Format to the COM Port. */
if(!SetCommState(hComPort, &dcbComConfig))
{
    printf("Error setting com to format data.\n");
}

/* Mask what events you want to look for in the COM Port. */
if (!SetCommMask(hComPort, dwStoredFlags))
{
    printf("Error setting communications mask\n");
}

/*-- Read Timeouts set like this so we can use the event based reading. --*/
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD; 
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;

if (!SetCommTimeouts(hComPort, &timeouts))
{
    printf("Error setting time-outs.\n");
}
```

### READING COM PORT

```
DWORD dwRead = 0;
DWORD dwComEvent = EV_RXCHAR;
DWORD lpErrors = 0;
char readBuffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];

/* Create the Overlapped IO Read Event. */
OVERLAPPED osRead = {0};
osRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

/* Used to monitor the COM Port State. */
COMSTAT ComStatus;

/* Loop at 20Hz to read the COM Port until a Kill event has been set. */
while(WaitForSingleObject(hKillEvent, 50) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    /* Wait for a COM Event to occur ( Read Event in this Case ). */
    if (WaitCommEvent(hComPort, &dwComEvent , NULL))
    {
        /* If the COM Port had an error Clear it. */
        ClearCommError(hComPort, &lpErrors, &ComStatus);
        /*-- Reset read operation's OVERLAPPED structure's hEvent --*/
        ResetEvent(osRead.hEvent);

        if (ReadFile(hComPort, readBuffer, ComStatus.cbInQue, &dwRead, &osRead))
        {
            /*-- bytes have been read; process it --*/
            USE_DATA(readBuffer, dwRead);
        }
        else
        {
            /*-- An error occurred in the ReadFile call --*/
            printf("ReadFile encountered an error.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        /*-- Error in WaitCommEvent --*/
        printf("WaitCommEvent encountered an error.\n");
        break;
    }
}

/* Close the Overlapped IO Read Event. */
CloseHandle(osRead.hEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is correct. In this case, opening with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, ReadFile expects an `OVERLAPPED` structure as last argument.

Would like to add that you can also get 'parameter is incorrect' error if you do supply an `OVERLAPPED` struct, but forget to `ZeroMemory` it.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-_overlapped):

> Any unused members of this structure should always be initialized to zero before the structure is used in a function call. Otherwise, the function may fail and return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

So don't forget to:

```
OVERLAPPED ovl;
ZeroMemory(&ovl, sizeof(ovl));
...
ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, &ovl);
```